# pandas read specific table

Tags: python, pandas

how can i get only AP ' "EO7" Hardware Information ' table from output like below. can i do this with pandas.

```
    AP "EO7" Basic Information
    ---------------------------------------
    Item            Value
    ----            -----
    AP IP Address   11.22.33.44
    LMS IP Address  2.2.2.2
    Group           aa
    Location Name   N/A
    Standby AAC     1.1.1.1 (last assigned at Fri Nov 11 03:14:06 2022 (5h:20m:50s ago); last sent at Fri Nov 11 03:14:06 2022 (5h:20m:50s ago), total sent 3)
    Status          Up
    Up time         8d:9h:14m:14s
    AP Flags:       ; Licensed; Ready for Standby; Standby Not Connected
    Installation    indoor
    
    AP "EO7" Hardware Information
    ------------------------------------------
    Item                Value
    ----                -----
    AP Type             105
    Serial #            BEaaaaaaa
    Wired MAC Address   d8:c7:c8:c9:aa:aa
    Radio 0 BSSID       d8:c7:c8:15:ac:a8              
    Radio 1 BSSID       d8:c7:c8:15:ac:da
    Radio 2 BSSID       N/A
    Enet 1 MAC Address  N/A
    Enet 2 MAC Address  N/A
    Enet 3 MAC Address  N/A
    Enet 4 MAC Address  N/A
    Enet 5 MAC Address  N/A
    Enet 6 MAC Address  N/A
    Enet 7 MAC Address  N/A
    
    AP "EO7" Operating Information
    -------------------------------------------
    Item                 Value
    ----                 -----
    AP State             Running
    Entry created        2022-11-10 09:15:24
    Last activity        2022-11-11 08:32:27
    Reboots              30
    Bootstraps           35596
    Bootstrap Threshold  8
    Port                 N/A
    
    AP "EO7" Radio 0 Operating Information
    ---------------------------------------------------
    Item                     Value    Source
    ----                     -----    ------
    High throughput          Enabled  Configuration
    Mode                     AP       Configuration
    Band                     802.11a  
    Max SSIDs                8        Configuration
    Primary Channel          120      AirMatch
    40MHz Secondary Channel  116      AirMatch
    EIRP                     17.0     AirMatch
    Cell size reduction      0 dB     
    
    AP "EO7" Radio 1 Operating Information
    ---------------------------------------------------
    Item                     Value    Source
    ----                     -----    ------
    High throughput          Enabled  Configuration
    Mode                     AP       Configuration
    Band                     802.11g  
    Max SSIDs                8        Configuration
    Channel                  1        AirMatch
    40MHz Secondary Channel  None     AirMatch
    EIRP                     6.0      AirMatch         
    802.11b Protection       Enabled  Configuration
    Cell size reduction      0 dB     
    
    AP "EO7" Provisioning Parameters
    ---------------------------------------------
    Item                                                              Value
    ----                                                              -----
    AP Name                                                           EO7
    AP Group                                                          AVM
    Location name                                                     N/A
    SNMP sysLocation                                                  mor 
    Master                                                            N/A
    Gateway                                                           N/A
    IPv6 Gateway                                                      N/A
    Netmask                                                           N/A
    IP Addr                                                           N/A
    IPv6 Addr                                                         N/A
    IPv6 Prefix                                                       64
    DNS IP                                                            N/A
    DNS IPv6                                                          N/A
    Domain Name                                                       N/A
    Server Name                                                       N/A
    Server IP                                                         N/A
    Antenna gain for 802.11a                                          N/A
    Radio 0 5GHz Antenna gain for APs support Dual 5GHz mode          N/A
    Radio 1 5GHz Antenna gain for APs support Dual 5GHz mode          N/A
    Antenna gain for 802.11g                                          N/A
    Antenna for 802.11a                                               both
    Antenna for 802.11g                                               both
    PKCS12 PASSPHRASE                                                 N/A
    Single chain mode for Radio 0                                     0
    Single chain mode for Radio 1                                     0
    External antenna polarization for 5GHz Radio                      0
    External antenna polarization for 2.4GHz Radio                    0
    Radio 0 5GHz Antenna polarization for APs support Dual 5GHz mode  0
    Radio 1 5GHz Antenna polarization for APs support Dual 5GHz mode  0
    TrustAnchor                                                       N/A
    IKE PSK                                                           N/A
    ikepsk-hex-based                                                  No
    PAP User Name                                                     N/A
    PAP Password                                                      N/A
    PPPOE User Name                                                   N/A
    PPPOE Password                                                    N/A
    PPPOE Service Name                                                N/A
    PPPOE CHAP Secret                                                 N/A
    USB User Name                                                     N/A
    USB Password                                                      N/A
    USB Device Type                                                   none
    USB CSR-Key Storage                                               No
    USB Device Identifier                                             N/A
    USB Dial String                                                   N/A
    USB Initialization String                                         N/A
    USB TTY device data path                                          N/A
    USB TTY device control path                                       N/A
    USB modeswitch parameters                                         N/A
    Uplink VLAN                                                       0
    Remote AP                                                         No
    OCSP Default                                                      N/A
    certificate DN                                                    N/A
    Link Priority Ethernet                                            0
    Link Priority Cellular                                            0
    Link Priority WiFi                                                0
    Cellular modem network preference                                 auto
    AP POE Power optimization                                         false
    AP LLDP PSE detection                                             disabled
    AP2xx prestandard POE detection                                   Disabled
    Mesh Role                                                         none
    Installation                                                      default
    Latitude                                                          N/A
    Longitude                                                         N/A
    Altitude                                                          N/A
    Antenna bearing for 802.11a                                       N/A
    Antenna bearing for 802.11g                                       N/A
    Antenna tilt angle for 802.11a                                    N/A
    Antenna tilt angle for 802.11g                                    N/A
    Username of AP so that AP can authenticate to 802.1x using PEAP   N/A
    Password of AP so that AP can authenticate to 802.1x using PEAP   N/A
    Enable AP to 802.1x using EAP-TLS                                 Disabled
    Enable AP to use factory certificates when doing 802.1x EAP-TLS   Disabled
    AP dot1x EAP-TLS username suffix                                  Disabled
    AP dot1x EAP-TLS username suffix domain                           aruba.ap
    AP Preferred Uplink Interface                                     N/A
    AP WiFi uplink                                                    Disabled
    Mesh SAE                                                          sae-disable*
```

Comment: Are you reading that as text?  This not a pandas problem, it's a simple Python parsing problem.  One line at a time, looking for key words.  What do you want the result to be?

Comment: I thought I could solve this with pandas. please share the solution if you can solve it in python.

Comment: We can't solve it, because we don't know what you want the output to be.  How are you going to use this?  Do you want a dictionary with the items and values?

Comment: I want to test what you said

Comment: You still haven't answered the question.  What are you trying to produce?  What would your output look like?

Comment: AP "EO7" Hardware Information
    ------------------------------------------
    Item                Value
    ----                -----
    AP Type             105
    Serial #            BEaaaaaaa
    Wired MAC Address   d8:c7:c8:c9:aa:aa
    Radio 0 BSSID       d8:c7:c8:15:ac:a8              
    Radio 1 BSSID       d8:c7:c8:15:ac:da
    Radio 2 BSSID       N/A
    Enet 1 MAC Address  N/A
    Enet 2 MAC Address  N/A
    Enet 3 MAC Address  N/A
    Enet 4 MAC Address  N/A
    Enet 5 MAC Address  N/A
    Enet 6 MAC Address  N/A
    Enet 7 MAC Address  N/A

this lile.

Comment: Hang on.  Are you asking, "how can I extract this information from a wireless access point"?  I assumed you had that information in a file and just wanted to parse it.  What hardware is this?

Comment: The output I get is the first long list I throw. from this long list i just want to read AP "EO7" Hardware Information table and assign it to a variable

Comment: But, a variable for what purpose?  Do you want those to be keys and values in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a starting point.

```
info = {}
capture = False
for line in  open("x.txt"):
    if not capture:
        capture = "Hardware Information" in line
        continue
    if "EO7" in line:
        break
    if "Item" in line:
        f1 = line.find("Item")
        f2 = line.find("Value")
    elif "----" not in line:
        key = line[f1:f2-1].strip()
        value = line[f2:].strip()
        if key:
            info[key] = value

from pprint import pprint
pprint(info)
```

Output:

```
{'AP Type': '105',
 'Enet 1 MAC Address': 'N/A',
 'Enet 2 MAC Address': 'N/A',
 'Enet 3 MAC Address': 'N/A',
 'Enet 4 MAC Address': 'N/A',
 'Enet 5 MAC Address': 'N/A',
 'Enet 6 MAC Address': 'N/A',
 'Enet 7 MAC Address': 'N/A',
 'Radio 0 BSSID': 'd8:c7:c8:15:ac:a8',
 'Radio 1 BSSID': 'd8:c7:c8:15:ac:da',
 'Radio 2 BSSID': 'N/A',
 'Serial #': 'BEaaaaaaa',
 'Wired MAC Address': 'd8:c7:c8:c9:aa:aa'}
```